# customize page is blank after installing wordpress 4.7.2

Tags: customization

I installed wordpress 4.7.2 from cPanel control panel using 'Softaculous Apps Installer'. The installer has setup the database automatically without any issues. I am able to login and could access other features except customize.

[image]

I did not change anything in the code. 
I logged in through wp-login and tried to customize by clicking the customize button. The page is blank. No error message was displayed. This is the first user interaction i did. 
I checked the error log in my server. There was nothing related to this path.

What is missing here?

**Additionally**

After a day of the above question I created another folder wordpress in my server and copied the zip file to that folder. I extracted and ran sitename.com/wordpress . It asked for database creds and provided. Installation was successful. Loggin page appeared and i logged in. I clicked customized button and got the following error

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   1200 bytes) in wp-includes/media.php on line 2813

Mine is a shared hosting environment.

I increased the limit to 512MB. Now the error did not appear but the page is blank. Back to zero.

Comment: Have you tried updating your WordPress installation through the update section in admin panel? WordPress 4.2 is pretty old. Updating to a fresh copy might solve your problem.

Comment: I am sorry. Typos.. it is 4.7.2

Comment: I have updated the version and the question to clear off the database puzzle

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: The default one. I did not change anything other than the site title.

Comment: Please try and enable the debug option in `wp-config.php` using `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, and see what error/warning does it return after visiting the customize panel.

Comment: I did that. it did not work. I started giving echo(the plain way of debugging) from customize.php to see where it is breaking. i reached the file wp-settings.php line number 436 where there is a function call do_action( 'after_setup_theme' ); . this is where it is breaking. an echo before this line works where as after this like it did not. may be i have to download a copy of wordpress files locally and have to see where the function is defined to see why it is breaking... I am no developer of wordpress so i am not sure i can get it solved. yet i will look into it. Meantime, you can help.

Comment: As i had said i copied the zip file to another dir named wordpress,  extracted and ran it as sitename.com/wordpress. I gave the database credentials and installed. After logging into the admin panel i clicked customize. I am getting an error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1200 bytes) in wp-includes/media.php on line 2813

Comment: After increasing the memory limit again a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a "test admin" user and see if you can access the customize page then? Also, silly question... but have you tried different browsers, clearing out cookies, etc..?

I would also disable all plugins - even the pre-installed plug-ins that come with a fresh Wordpress install. If that doesn't work, try to activate another "default" theme and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with Softaculous, but when you first time running WordPress, point your URL to `www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php` to setup the site. Also, have you create a database for WordPress yet? White-screen-of-dead could be many reasons, but giving that this is a fresh installation, it is most likely due to database has not been setup properly yet. See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors) for more information. If this still not working, provide your directory structure on how the wordpress is installed and the wp-config.php setting related to `'DB_NAME'` and `'DB_HOST'` for further diagnostic.

Comment: he mentioned that he is able to log in to the admin panel, which means the database is set up properly and the installation is done.